# Can't read new product attribute in template

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, template, data

I added a new attribute to a product. The attribute is named "**is_brand_new**". The product shows in the catalog product view in the upselling and related slider.

But the new attribute is not in the product data. I even cleared the cache

I outputted all the data from the item

**app\design\frontend\company\base\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list\items.phtml**:

```
if ($_item->getData("name") == "t-shirt") {
    var_dump($_item->getData());
}
```

But it does not contain the data for the attribute `is_brand_new`.

What I try to do is show an icon if the product is marked as brandnew.
So I added a new checkbox attribute in the backend. Now I try to read it out and show the icon if the checkbox is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the block classes prepareData method is only loading a few attributes. So I had to create a helper, load the full product via the ID, then I was able to load the attribute.

**Helper:**

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

...

public function getProductByIdAndReturnData($id, $key)
{
    $product = $this->getProductById($id);
    if (empty($product)) { return $this; }

    $data = $product->getData($key);
    return $data;
}

public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}
```

**Template:**

```
$isProductBrandNew = $productHelper->getProductByIdAndReturnData($id, "is_brand_new");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you setup thr product attribute to be visible in front from the backend as per the screenshot below, the attribute should appear.

[image]